# WPF: CommandBinding returns originalSource ListView, not the expected ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I Create a context menu for a child ListViewItem and added a delete command.
Everything works as expected when I rightclicked the element and select the delete item, everything works as expected and the client is deleted.
But when I select the element and press delete, it will call DeleteClient_Executed with the OriginalSource set to the ListView, and not the selected ListViewItem. So the databinding wont work as expected.

I can do a simple workaround, check the type and search the selected ListViewItem, but I want to understand why it happens, and maybe find a cleaner solution.

the xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="oasis.ClientList"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:oasis"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             MinWidth="100"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="100">
    <UserControl.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding x:Name="DeleteClient" Command="Delete" Executed="DeleteClient_Executed" CanExecute="DeleteClient_CanExecute"/>
    </UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <StackPanel Margin="10,0">
        <TextBox Name="Searchbar" TextChanged="Searchbar_TextChanged" />
        <ListView Name="Clients">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="local:Client">
                    <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Command="Delete" CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

the cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace oasis
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ClientList.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ClientList : UserControl
    {
        public ClientList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ListClients();
        }

        public void ListClients()
        {
            Clients.ItemsSource = Db.ListClients(Searchbar.Text);
        }

        private void Searchbar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListClients();
        }

        private void DeleteClient_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((Client)((ListViewItem)e.OriginalSource).DataContext).Delete();
            ListClients();
        }

        private void DeleteClient_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.OriginalSource.GetType() == typeof(ListViewItem))
            {
                e.CanExecute = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```